# INSERT multiple times

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I need to insert multiple rows in MySQL.

Like this:

```
INSERT INTO  `table` ( `X` , `Y` , `Z`)VALUES (DEFAULT,  '1',  '1')
INSERT INTO  `table` ( `X` , `Y` , `Z`)VALUES (DEFAULT,  '2',  '2')
INSERT INTO  `table` ( `X` , `Y` , `Z`)VALUES (DEFAULT,  '3',  '3')
```

I got this error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO `table` ( `X` , `Y` , `Z` ' at line 2

I tried with `;` and `,` at the end of each insert, but nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with separeated query

```
INSERT INTO  `table` ( `X` , `Y` , `Z`) VALUES (DEFAULT,  '1',  '1');
INSERT INTO  `table` ( `X` , `Y` , `Z`) VALUES (DEFAULT,  '2',  '2');
INSERT INTO  `table` ( `X` , `Y` , `Z`) VALUES (DEFAULT,  '3',  '3');
```

or  with a query only

```
INSERT INTO  `table` ( `X` , `Y` , `Z`) VALUES 
 (DEFAULT,  '1',  '1'),(DEFAULT,  '2',  '2'), (DEFAULT,  '3',  '3');
```

;

Comment: INSERT INTO  `table` ( `X` , `Y` , `Z`)VALUES 
 (DEFAULT,  '1',  '1'),(DEFAULT,  '2',  '2'), (DEFAULT,  '3',  '3');

solve it! thanks you